# Не работает поиск на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Недавно сделал пагинацию на сайте. Она выглядит вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но теперь не работает поиск по базе данных. Когда нажимаю на поиск он отображает все записи. Я наверное что-то не могу разобраться. Код пагинации на php:

```
<?
                // функция вывода
                function pagePrint($page, $title, $show, $active_class = '') {
                    if($show) {
                        echo '<a href="course_db.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $title . '</a>';
                    } else {
                        if(!empty($active_class)) $active = 'class="' . $active_class . '"';
                        echo '<span ' . $active . '>' . $title . '</span>';
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                // начальный конфиг
                $page_setting = [
                    'limit' => 5,
                    'show' => 3,
                    'prev_show' => 0,
                    'next_show' => 0,
                    'first_show' => 0,
                    'last_show' => 0,
                    'prev_text' => 'назад',
                    'next_text' => 'вперед',
                    'class_active' => 'active',
                    'separator' => '...',
                ];

                // получение данных
                $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
                if($page < 1) $page = 1;

                // подсчет страниц
                $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS id FROM `course` ");
                $sql->execute();
                $custCount = $sql->fetchAll();
                $row = $custCount[0]['id'];
                $page_count = ceil($row / $page_setting['limit']);
                $page_left = $page - $page_setting['show'];
                $page_right = $page + $page_setting['show'];
                if($page_left < 2) $page_left = 2;
                if($page_right > ($page_count - 1)) $page_right = $page_count - 1;
                if($page != 1) {
                    $page_prev = $page - 1;
                    $page_setting['prev_show'] = 1;
                    $page_setting['first_show'] = 1;
                }
                if($page != $page_count) {
                    $page_setting['next_show'] = 1;
                    $page_setting['last_show'] = 1;
                    $page_next = $page + 1;
                }

                // вывод на экран
                pagePrint($page_prev, $page_setting['prev_text'], $page_setting['prev_show']);
                pagePrint(1, 1, $page_setting['first_show'], $page_setting['class_active']);

                if($page_left > 2) echo $page_setting['separator'];

                for($i = $page_left; $i <= $page_right; $i++){
                    $page_show = 1;
                    if($page == $i) $page_show = 0;
                    pagePrint($i, $i, $page_show, $page_setting['class_active']);
                }

                if($page_right < ($page_count - 1)) echo $page_setting['separator'];

                if($page_count != 1) pagePrint($page_count, $page_count, $page_setting['last_show'], $page_setting['class_active']);

                pagePrint($page_next, $page_setting['next_text'], $page_setting['next_show']);

                $start = ($page - 1)*$page_setting['limit'];
                $sql1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course`  LIMIT {$start}, {$page_setting['limit']}");
                $sql1->execute();
                $result = $sql1->fetchAll();
            ?>

    
$search = $_GET['search'];
        $search_2 = $_GET['search_2'];
        $search_3 = $_GET['search_3'];
        $search_4 = $_GET['search_4'];
        $search_5 = $_GET['search_5'];
        $search_6 = $_GET['search_6'];
        $search_7 = $_GET['search_7'];
        $search_8 = $_GET['search_8'];
        $search_9 = $_GET['search_9'];
        $search_10 = $_GET['search_10'];
    if ($search !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  nomer_kabineta LIKE '$search'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_2 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Nazvanie_kabineta LIKE '%' '%$search_2%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_4 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  nomer_korpusa LIKE '$search_4'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_5 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Adress LIKE '%' '%$search_5%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_6 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Facultet_naimenovanie LIKE '%' '%$search_6%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_7 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Tip_tehniki LIKE '%' '%$search_7%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_8 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  OC LIKE '%' '%$search_8%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_9 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Inventarniy_nomer LIKE '%' '%$search_9%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
    if ($search_10 !='' ) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE  Harakteristiki LIKE '%' '%$search_10%'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();    
        }
```

Comment: Для ограничения количества выводимых результатов поиска используйте `LIMIT`

Comment: @br3t, это я знаю, у меня в другом проблема, то что когда я делаю поиск, то не отображаются данные по этому запросу, а просто отображаются все записи как на картинке вверху

Comment: Проверьте синтаксис вашего `LIKE` [пример](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)